# PDO getting only one value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am querying a database for the latest row entered and get the id column only, so I am sure I will get one value. However, I am unable to print the variable unless it is in a `foreach` loop, not even accessing the 0th element is giving me any output.

I use this line of code for querying the latest row's id added: `$id = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM FM;");`

When I use the `foreach` loop, I get the following output:

Loop:

```
foreach ($id as $i)
    print_r($i);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [MAX(id)] => 20 [0] => 20 )
```

However, when I use `print $id[0];` or `print $id["MAX(id)"];` I get the HTTP Error 500.

How can I get the single value id and put it in a variable, the id itself that is?

Thanks

Comment: use this `print($id[0]);` instead of `print $id[0];;` or `echo $id[0];`

Comment: `print($id[0]);` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting max(id) you have to use `lastInsertId()` method

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

right after calling insert query

Comment: Didn't notice you called `lastInsertId()` on `$db`, it worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I looked up in the `PDOStatement` reference which is returned fromt the `query` function, and found the `fetchAll()` method which returns an array of rows, and got the latest id by the following line of code: `$id->fetchAll()[0][0];`

Comment: +1 to -aizen-.  yes this is one option. that is great here and also the error I think because of that you try to print an object's item as index of array. I mean you should do `print($id[0]->id); or at least print_r($id[0]);`